# Unknown behaviour with Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to implement a Java Stop Watch in which I have used a Thread to continuously moniter time elapsed. But i have encountered a problem in my code. 
My Java Code is -

```
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.util.Calendar;

  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Prac2_StopWatch implements ActionListener{
      JFrame Time;
      JLabel TimeLabel;
      JButton StartStop;
      JButton Reset;
      StopWatch stThread;
      String prefix="<html><h1><body>";
      String suffix="</h1></body></html>";
      StopWatch myControl;

      Prac2_StopWatch()
     {
         Time = new JFrame();
         Time.setSize(275,275);
         Time.setTitle("Stop Watch");
         Time.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
         GridBagConstraints gridConst = new GridBagConstraints();

         TimeLabel = new JLabel();
         TimeLabel.setText(prefix+"0:0:0"+suffix);

         myControl = new StopWatch(TimeLabel);
         myControl.start();

         StartStop = new JButton();
         Reset = new JButton();

         StartStop.setActionCommand("Start");
         StartStop.setText("Start");
         Reset.setText("Reset");

         StartStop.addActionListener(this);
         Reset.addActionListener(this);

         gridConst.gridx=0;
         gridConst.gridy=0;
         Time.add(StartStop,gridConst);

         gridConst.gridx=1;
         gridConst.gridy=0;
         Time.add(Reset,gridConst);

         gridConst.gridx=0;
         gridConst.gridy=1;
         Time.add(TimeLabel,gridConst);

         Time.setVisible(true);



      }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
     {
         if(evt.getActionCommand()=="Start")
         {
            StartStop.setActionCommand("Stop");
            StartStop.setText("Stop");
            if(myControl.curMil==-1)
                 myControl.curMil=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            else 
                myControl.curMil=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()-      myControl.diff;
                myControl.count=true;

             }
            else if(evt.getActionCommand()=="Stop")
           {
              StartStop.setActionCommand("Start");
              StartStop.setText("Start");
              myControl.count=false;

           }
           else if(evt.getActionCommand()=="Reset")
           {
               StartStop.setActionCommand("Start");
               StartStop.setText("Start");
               myControl.count=false;
               myControl.curMil=-1;
               TimeLabel.setText(prefix+"0:0:0"+suffix);

           }
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run()
                {
                   new Prac2_StopWatch();
                }
             });

        }
   }

   class StopWatch extends Thread
   {
        long curMil;
        long diff;
        JLabel TimeLabel;
        boolean count;
        String prefix="<html><body><h1>";
        String suffix="</h1></body></html>";

        StopWatch(JLabel TimeLabel)
        {
           this.TimeLabel = TimeLabel;
           this.count=false;
           this.curMil=-1;
         }
       public void run()
       {
           while(true){
           System.out.print("Commenting this line will make stop watch useless");
           if(count){
                diff= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - curMil;
                TimeLabel.setText(prefix+((diff/60000)%60)+" : "+((diff/1000)%60)+" : "+(diff%1000)+suffix);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

Now the problem is that in the run method of StopWatch class when I comment the statement -

```
System.out.println("Commenting this line will make stop watch useless");
```

in line 123.
My stop watch stops working i.e. the clock always displays "0:0:0" even if press 'Start', 'Stop' or 'Reset'. Moreover, replacing the line 123 with any other statement other than 'System.out.println()' has the same issue.

Comment: What is *line 123*. Do you want us to count to it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I may be wrong but wouldn't `Thread.sleep` result in an inaccurate timing?

Comment: @Cking I have also shown what is in line 123. System.out.println("Commenting this line will make stop watch useless");. Will you please tell me how much more clear i could have asked.

Comment: You all are right that relying on Thread.sleep for timing in inappropraite but here the issue is about clock not working when I just remove or comment one line. Help in that direction is appreciated. Also I have executed this code several time on several other machines but it has shown me the same behaviour

Comment: You're also making Swing calls from the background thread, and **that** is not allowed and risky. Don't do that.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I have increased the time in Thread.sleep() but it made no difference. Moreover the problem occurs also when my Program has only main thread and no other thread i.e. without using SwingUtilities.invokeLater .... part

Comment: Make count `volatile`. You're using it between threads, and it must be updated in all threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main problems that I see:

- <strike>You've got a tight loop, one with a 1 msec pause that will hog the processor</strike> [Edit: this is actually OK]
- You're making Swing calls, here `setText(...)` from your background thread, something that you shouldn't be doing, and that with the tight loop can completely freeze your Swing GUI.
- You're sharing the count boolean variable between threads, and so it must be declared `volatile` so that its state will be the same in all threads.

If you need to make Swing state changes from within a background thread, use a SwingWorker and make the changes using the publish/process pair.

Also, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
else if (evt.getActionCommand() == "Stop") {
```

do

```
else if (evt.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prac2_StopWatch implements ActionListener {
    JFrame time;
    JLabel timeLabel;
    JButton startStop;
    JButton reset;
    StopWatch stThread;
    String prefix = "<html><h1><body>";
    String suffix = "</h1></body></html>";
    StopWatch myControl;

    Prac2_StopWatch() {
        time = new JFrame();

        time.setSize(275, 275);
        time.setTitle("Stop Watch");
        time.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        time.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridConst = new GridBagConstraints();

        timeLabel = new JLabel();
        timeLabel.setText(prefix + "00:00:000" + suffix);

        myControl = new StopWatch(timeLabel);
        new Thread(myControl).start(); // StopWatch should implement Runnable
        // myControl.start();

        startStop = new JButton();
        reset = new JButton();

        startStop.setActionCommand("Start");
        startStop.setText("Start");
        reset.setText("Reset");

        startStop.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        time.add(startStop, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 1;
        gridConst.gridy = 0;
        time.add(reset, gridConst);

        gridConst.gridx = 0;
        gridConst.gridy = 1;
        time.add(timeLabel, gridConst);

        time.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
            startStop.setActionCommand("Stop");
            startStop.setText("Stop");
            if (myControl.getCurMil() == -1)
                myControl.setCurMil(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            else
                myControl.setCurMil(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - myControl.getDiff());
            myControl.count = true;

        } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")) {
            startStop.setActionCommand("Start");
            startStop.setText("Start");
            myControl.count = false;

        } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Reset")) {
            startStop.setActionCommand("Start");
            startStop.setText("Start");
            myControl.count = false;
            myControl.setCurMil(-1);
            timeLabel.setText(prefix + "00:00:000" + suffix);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Prac2_StopWatch();
            }
        });

    }
}

class StopWatch implements Runnable {
    private long curMil;
    private long diff;
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    // *************** this is key ****************
    volatile boolean count; // !! *********************

    String prefix = "<html><body><h1>";
    String suffix = "</h1></body></html>";

    StopWatch(JLabel TimeLabel) {
        this.timeLabel = TimeLabel;
        this.count = false;
        this.curMil = -1;
    }

    public long getCurMil() {
        return curMil;
    }

    public void setCurMil(long curMil) {
        this.curMil = curMil;
    }

    public long getDiff() {
        return diff;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // System.out.println("Commenting this line will make stop watch useless");
            if (count) {
                diff = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - curMil;

                // make Swing changes **on** the event thread only
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    int mSec = (int) (diff % 1000);
                    int sec = (int) ((diff / 1000) % 60);
                    int min = (int) ((diff / (60 * 1000)) % 60);
                    String text = String.format("%s%02d:%02d:%03d%s", prefix, min, sec, mSec, suffix);
                    timeLabel.setText(text);
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);  // ** actually 1 is OK **
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move

```
if(count){
  diff= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - curMil;
  TimeLabel.setText(prefix+((diff/60000)%60)+":"+((diff/1000)%60)+" : "+(diff%1000)+suffix);
}
```

inside `try-catch` block.

Side notes:

1. Your program doesn't stops when `JFrame` window is closed. Use

   ```
   Time.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   ```
2. Proper way to compare Strings in java is

   ```
   if("string1".equals("string2")) {
       //do stuff
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you please explain why try-catch solved the issue?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks a lot, but it is not me :)

Comment: @sergpank: ah gotcha. His main problem is that the boolean variable is not volatile.